# ModelSim PE Student Edition licensing issue

Tags: modelsim

I have written some VHDL code which compiles fine in Quartus Prime Lite edition. I'd now like to setup a test bench in order to simulate the code. I'm following a tutorial by Intel ([link to youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qZNL1C0TwY8&t=61s)) which says that after analysis and synthesis I go to tools -> run simulation tool -> RTL simulation. This launches modelsim. I have the student version installed with the license key placed in the root install directory. When I right click on my entity to try and select "create wave" this button is greyed out which it is not in the tutorial. I've shown this below:

[image: Modelsim]

If i double click on the entity I get this error down in the transcript window:

```
** Error: ModelSim PE Student Edition license key file not found at C:\Modeltech_pe_edu_10.4a\win32pe_edu\..\student_license.dat.
# ** FATAL ERROR: ModelSim PE Student Edition licensing failure due to one or more problems with the license key such as:

# ** FATAL ERROR: ModelSim PE Student Edition licensing failure due to one or more problems with the license key such as:
# - it is not found
# - it has expired
# - it is not for this user
# - it is not for this computer
# - it is not for this version of ModelSim PE Student Edition.
# 
# Please go to http://www.model.com and download an updated copy of the ModelSim PE Student Edition.
# Error loading design
```

However I have placed the license file where the error says it is looking for the file - in C:\Modeltech_pe_edu_10.4a\win32pe_edu\ however I still get the error.

update: Another site suggested adding an environment variable to the location. I added "LM_LICENSE_FILE" to environment variables and still get the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Copy student_license.dat file in C:\Modeltech_pe_edu_10.4a\ as well as in C:\Modeltech_pe_edu_10.4a\win32pe_edu,
- After copying go back to desktop, right click on ModelSim PE student edition
- Click on run as administrator.

Answer (score 1):

while this is not really an answer for your question, I would install the starter edition of modelsim (ModelSim*-Intel® FPGA Starter Edition)

from intel: https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/software/programmable/quartus-prime/model-sim.html

if you design is small, it will work without a license fight.

now, if you absolutely need the PE version because your design is too big for the free version, you will need to fix your license issue.

We will need a bit more context of your installation, but here some (maybe) help:

you need to run the daemon (named flexlm) which will provide the license to modelsim.

look at the install doc: https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/programmable/us/en/pdfs/literature/manual/quartus_install.pdf

=> look at: "4.4. Configuring the License Manager Server"

=> look at: "Specifying the License for the ModelSim - Intel FPGA Edition Software"